# Strange erb behaviour when making table inside table

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I'm trying to simply have a table appear inside a `<td>` element of an outer table. This code:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
    <td>
        <table border="0" class="timesList">
            <tbody>
                <% @time_array.each do |time| %>
                    <tr><%= time %></tr>
                <% end %>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

However, when erb renders the html for this page, I get:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
    <td>
                 9:0010:00:11:0012:00
        <table border="0" class="timesList">
                            <tr></tr>
                            <tr></tr>
                            <tr></tr>
                            <tr></tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? I am just missing something blatantly obvious? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because the `<td></td>` are missing

```
<tr><td><%= time %></td></tr>
```

Your browser failed to parse the table and put the unexpected text "9:0010:00:11:0012:00" outside the table when rendering the source.

Comment: Yes! I posted the question and went to go get a coffee. Realized the obvious while standing in line. Thanks